# Is there any GitHub GUI Client for Linux OS?

Tags: github

Is there anything similar to [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) or [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/) for Linux systems?

Comment: This question has been closed for more than 3 years. Can we migrate it to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I would recommend using [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/). It is cross platform and integrates with GitHub.

Comment: +1 for GitKraken. Though it looks like Github has rebooted their desktop clients. They are now built on Electron, so it's conceivable that a Linux version isn't too far off now.

Comment: There is now: https://github.com/desktop/desktop

Comment: There are GitHub Desktop alpha releases available for Linux at https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop/releases

Answer (score 28):

Try the [SmartGitHg](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/download/). It's a Git GUI that both support Windows and Linux. And it supports GitHub very well.

Comment: +1 for SmartGitHg. It's the best GUI that I've yet.

Answer (score 2):

I assume [git-cola](http://git-cola.github.com/downloads.html) does what you are looking for. It is not specifically for GitHub, but it allows working with Git and its repositories in general. It is [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29)-based and should work on any Linux desktop.